# Why does Node run slower on Windows than on Macos?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos

I try to build a simple react app use `npm run build` on same machine(Macbook Pro) in difference system, It takes 4s more time in windows than in mac.

Comment: It is more than likely hardware related and there are a lot of other variables that could come into play

Comment: Windows is well known to suck at disk I/O. In the mid-2000s someone benchmarked Windows vs Windows running in VMWare on Linux and found that the Windows running on Linux performed better as a file server.

Comment: I use `npm install` it spend the same time.but I run the jest test ,windows slower too

Answer (score 0):

It might be your antivirus slowing it down. Try adding npm, node, and whatever else you're using to your AV's ignore list. Don't know why, but some users have had that issue before.

Make sure to check that you're not using unneeded dependencies or extensions in your IDE.

(I would've commented this, but I don't have enough rep)